# How to permanently switch off discrete graphic card?

Tags: vgaswitcheroo

I got a integrated GD, which is Intel, and another discrete GD, AMD Radeon 6490 HD
I am using ubuntu 11.10

1st, when I boot into Windows, my GD is indeed AMD Radeon 6490 HD, but when I boot into Ubuntu, it shows that I have AMD Radeon 6470 instead.

2nd, I try most methods only to install driver for my AMD/ATI graphic card. First by jockey(fail, boot with unity 2D instead) and install manually (fail, boot into blank screen).

3rd, I give up using the AMD/ATI graphic card. Then I got a new problem. Both my graphic cards are powered on on startup, which causes my laptop to over heat.

I view the content of `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`

```
0:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

Then I switch off IGD using `echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` and I get

```
0:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

But after I reboot, the discrete graphic card is powered on again. How to solve this?

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simplistic way would be to add `echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` to `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0` so it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

exit 0
```

Comment: Is this really all you have to do? Just add this one line? Is does not change anything for me. `glxinfo` still shows: `Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS`

Comment: I've noticed that I don't have `vgaswitcheroo`, but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

@gentmatt -  I have a Sony VAIO with hybrid graphics and I had the same problem of not seeing vgaswitcheroo in the location that various forum posts mention.  After some trial an error I discovered that it wasn't there after I'd installed AMD catalyst drivers (that didn't work properly) via the 'Additional Drivers' indicator after installing 12.04.  I tried purging the AMD drivers but it didn't help... I ended up having to reinstall Ubuntu and made sure not to install the Additional Drivers.  After doing this the same method posted by @Oli works for me. vgaswitcheroo is there, my discrete card is OFF, and my laptop runs nice and cool!  Hope this helps...