# Disabling Discrete GPU At Startup without System Crash

Tags: graphics, startup

I have a hard-wired (i.e not multiplex) Nvidia GeForce 540m discrete GPU with an integrated Intel graphics card.

I have no need for the discrete graphics card and am trying to disable it completely (at the moment, they are both powered on).

I am familiar with [HybridGraphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) on Ubuntu and the various on/off commands, and read these two posts to help me achieve this

[How to permanently switch off discrete graphic card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89205/how-to-permanently-switch-off-discrete-graphic-card)

and this from [UbuntuGuide](http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-12-04-turn-off-discrete-graphic-card-on-boot).

Unfortunately, both the tutorials suggest editing `/etc/rc.local` file by adding switcheroo commands. I have tried this and my system completely refuses to boot when I edit the `rc.local`; I had to restore the original file to regain access Ubuntu.

Are there other methods which I can use to disable my GPU safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumblebee is the solution for Ubuntu 12.04 and later with Nvidia. Ubuntu 13.10 officially support Bumblebee. It is the best solution and you can switch between graphics as you please anytime. No crashes i promise :)
http://cantstopgeeking.blogspot.in/2014/03/bumblebee-best-way-to-disable-discrete.html

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it in your bios under Graphic settings, I can't tell you exactly where the option is on you're laptop because every BIOS is different, but it will look something like this: [image]

Comment: Right, this is usually for Lenovo laptops. I have a Dell XPS 15 which does not have this option :/