# vgaswitcheroo doesn't work on 14.04 - discrete Radeon always on, Dell Vostro 3350

Tags: ati, graphics, 14.04, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I've a following problem - I've just upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 on my Dell Vostro 3350 and I can't turn off the discrete graphics. As instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89205/how-to-permanently-switch-off-discrete-graphic-card) and following [HybridGraphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) I managed to permanently turn off my secondary Radeon graphics in 13.10, though now the same operation doesn't work. After enabling the `vgaswitheroo` and typing in terminal `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` output looks like this

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

instead of

```
0:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

I saw in 13.10. The effect is exactly the same as if discrete graphics is on, laptop is loud and terribly overheats. Typing `sudo echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` gives no effect, output of `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` doesn't change. I tried some additional commands, like suggested [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/103263/239808), didn't help thought. 14.04 installation is brand new, this was the first thing I tried to set up, so my guess I miss something, no idea what though. I would appreciate some help with this issue, as it increases temperatures detected by `sensors` by almost 20 degrees compared to those with discrete graphics off, which, well, is defiantly not good for the hardware.

Thanks!

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/451021/202806

Comment: Doesn't work.

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

exit 0

in rc.local gives

0:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0

no changes.

Comment: but it's an accepted answer http://askubuntu.com/a/89213/202806

Comment: Yes it is, not for 14.04 though. As I wrote, I knew how to do this before, it worked for me on 13.10, now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I am having a similar problem with an Acer Aspire 5820TG laptop (Intel / Radeon 5650) after the upgrade. However the DynOff condition is not a problem for overheating in my case. The only annoying thing is that X.org connects to this card as a screen which powers up the card and I have to disable it using arandr.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable ATI discrete graphic GPU at startup in Ubuntu 14.04 without BIOS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450410/how-can-i-disable-ati-discrete-graphic-gpu-at-startup-in-ubuntu-14-04-without-bi)

Answer (score 1):

" saw in 13.10. The effect is exactly the same as if discrete graphics is on, laptop is loud and terribly overheats. Typing sudo `echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` gives no effect, output of `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` doesn't change."

from my experience, DynOff works better than manual Off. It still says Off (DynOff) and I guess that it means the card is not powered and that this is automatic.

However, if you still want to roll things back to the manual settings, you have to modify grub.  Use `sudo` to do the following:

open in any editor the file `/etc/default/grub`  and find the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

there should be values like "quiet splash" in this line; just add radeon.runpm=0 so it looks something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.runpm=0"
```

save the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot. after rebooting, the behavior of `cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` should be like in older ubuntu version. then you can run

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitheroo/switch
```

to see if it works - as you used to do before. if it works, add this line to `/etc/rc.local` just above `exit 0`.

i tried it on my machine and it basically works... but i think that DynOff is doing exactly the same. my computer is not overheating with both configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and confirm in comments if this works...

http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2014/07/disable-radeon-power-management-newer-linux-kernels/.

For me, during first reboot it gave a low graphics mode. Then, I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F2, and then ran the cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch, where it showed "Off" infront of DIS. Then, I ran sudo shutdown now -r to reboot. Finally,in the next reboot it worked. Also, I edited the etc/rc.local file to make this change permanent. Although I used Ubuntu 12.04.5, but I used the latest kernel 3.13...which, I believe, is the source of the problem, due to the recent changes in discrete graphics handling method.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot confirm anymore, I got rid of the equipment months ago...

Comment: @Voii Well, it works pretty nice for me. There were some problems with Linux 3.13.0-39. However after trying on a fresh install in Ubuntu, I realized may be this was due to Intel Open Source driver as it worked pretty nice. This in combination with tlp and http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html works fantastic for me. Anyways, thanks for commenting. :)

Answer (score 0):

on the arch forum https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1301253 I have found working xorg.conf which helps me. Now power consumption of my notebook is 10.7W instead of 12.6W in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.