# VCE init error (-22) with Slow Boot & Driver Problem on 16.04

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, radeon

My machine is Lenovo running ubuntu 16.04 and it has two vga controller (Intel and Radeon). But only Intel shows up.

```
$ sudo lspci | grep "VGA" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

& whenever my machine boots up it come up with following error(image in the link) causing slow boot.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1FY6.jpg)

& the code 
`dmesg | egrep -i 'vce|error'` leads to the following error:

```
[    1.556359] button: probe of PNP0C0D:01 failed with error -17
[    2.080041] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
[    2.080048] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.RP05.PEGP.DD02._BCL] (Node ffff88015a8fc0f0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
[    2.121858] radeon 0000:03:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[   15.077591] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   23.732375] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   28.002873] radeon 0000:03:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[   38.953480] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   44.281773] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   45.127882] radeon 0000:03:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[   59.498891] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   65.139303] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 7, error -71
```

What's the reason behind all these and how can I solve slow boot & not showing Radeon Graphics problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem too,i spend much time to solve the problem,I'm sure that the graphic having no driver. there have somebody give some answer:

[I can not find /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53054/i-can-not-find-sys-kernel-debug-vgaswitcheroo-switch)

[vgaswitcheroo doesn't work on 14.04 - discrete Radeon always on, Dell Vostro 3350](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450993/vgaswitcheroo-doesnt-work-on-14-04-discrete-radeon-always-on-dell-vostro-335)

Above answer in BIOS `Switchable Graphics` mode,I can't slove my problem.i guess if you want solve the problem,you must install the graphic driver or off the Discrete Graphics.I almost don't use discrete graphics, So i change the BIOS graphic mode as `UMA Graphics` to off the Discrete Graphics.and then the error about `radeon 0000:03:00.0: VCE init error (-22)` disappeared.

and the error with usb, there have the same question:
[USB device not accepting address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117524/usb-device-not-accepting-address)