# Permanently Disable external Graphics Card (usb)

Tags: usb, graphics, multiple-monitors

I've got this cooling pad with USB-hub, LAN-Port, Audio and a VGA-Port. It's all connected to the computer via USB. So I guess it's basically an external Graphics-Card for the VGA.

**Long:**

It didn't work for a long while, which was okay. With some update in the past it started working, which was cool. But it always shows up as a screen, even if no Screen is connected to the VGA. And I realized that as soon as something a little complicated (like a video) is running it makes the frame rate go down drastically (even on the onboard-screen).

Anyway, it works fine if I go to "Settings > Display" and disable it. Unfortunatly I switch screens a lot and it's very annoying to disable it manually (and when I connect two more screen (I have to use three screens sometimes) Ubuntu has trouble handling four screens (which is fine too)).

**Short:**

I want to disable the VGA-Port (or graphic card?) permanently. Maybe also the other stuff (LAN/Audio).

Thanks in advance!

---

P.s.: The only thing I found close to this was: [How to permanently switch off discrete graphic card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89205/how-to-permanently-switch-off-discrete-graphic-card) but the folder (or any similar) does not exist....